# access SDBM files in C#

Tags: c#, perl, hash, persistence

I'm used to use SDBM files in Perl to persistently store hashes. In Perl this is easy:

```
my %hash;
tie (%hash, 'SDBM_File', "filename", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
```

(http://perldoc.perl.org/SDBM_File.html)

This connects the hash with the two files "filename.dir" and "filename.pag". Any changes made to the content of the hash is then persistently stored to these files.

I'd like to access (read and write) these existing files using C#, but found no solution yet. Any ideas?

Comment: See: https://github.com/davidar/sdbm & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx  & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is very straightforward to embed a Perl interpreter into a C program which will let you code the hash access in Perl. I assume the same will be possible in C#

It will increase the size of your executable, but shouldn't make it significantly slower once the Perl code has been compiled

Take a look at [**perlembed**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) for details. Also look at [*Perl in C#*](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=530344) on **perlmonks.org** for more help on the C# side of things